# How to automate deployments of Bot Channels Registration in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-bot-service

We're using **Bot Channels Registration** in Azure and it gets created as a separate resource in my Resource Group. Now I would like to add it to my ARM template based deployment. Unfortunately I can't see any **Automation** option when I open the resource:

[image]

I've also tried to generate Automation template for entire Resource Group but **Bot Channels Registration** is not being added in that case.

I can't find anything on ARM templates [page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) either.

Any ideas how to get the template for this resource ? Or maybe I could create it directly from Powershell as a workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have resource type "Microsoft.BotService/botServices" to accomplish the requirement of creating Bot Channels Registration using ARM template.
For more details w.r.t this, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.botservice/2018-07-12/botservices

I was able to create Bot Channels Registration resource using the same ARM template. For illustration see below screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)

Just FYI, we also have ARM templates for channels, enterprise channels, connections. For more details w.r.t these, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.botservice/allversions